# "You need to format the disk in drive" but I cannot access the drive

Tags: usb-flash-drive, data-recovery, restore, hard-drive-recovery

Whenever I plug in my thumbdrive into my computer, I get:

> You need to format the disk in drive D: before you can use it.

I tried a solution suggested, `chkdsk D:/f` (and `/r`) in the command line but got

> Cannot open volume for direct access.

Furthermore, I cannot see the drive in the file explorer nor in the recovery tool I downloaded (MiniTool POwer Data Recovery). Drive `D:` shortly pops up in the file explorer and then disappears. This USB drive exhibits exactly the same problem on any other computer I open it on.

How can I make the drive accessible again to start data recovery process?

Comment: Best guess: it's dead, bin it. They're really not worth messing with once they start to fail.

Comment: The data on the USB drive is very important though and there is no other copy of it.

Comment: Then you just learned a very important lesson. **Any data stored in less than three distinct locations ought to be considered temporary.** You could try PhotoRec, but idk if it can function if nothing even at hardware level is seeing the drive.